# Android: Загрузка изображения в кэш для дальнейшего использования

Tags: java, android

Я неопытен в операциях с файлами в Android.
Мне нужно отобразить `GridView` c предпросмотром изображений, которые скачиваются из интернета. Использую кастомный адаптер, в котором происходит парсинг остальных данных в объекты списка. Я понял, что загружать битмап прямо в `getView` совсем не вариант, ибо это будет очень сильно тормозить основной поток, плюс придется постоянно заново загружать те элементы, которые выгружались для экономии озу. Я пришел к выводу, что нужно загрузить нужные изображения в кэш в отдельном потоке, а потом из него брать их и отрисовывать в объектах. Перерыл весь гугл, но так и не нашел, как просто загрузить изображения в кэш. Желательно без всяких сторонних библиотек.

Comment: Рекомендую не изобретать велосипед, а все-таки воспользоваться библиотеками. Если не стоит принципиальной задачи их избегать, возьмите Picasso или Glide. И лучше использовать `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`, а не `GridView`

Comment: Кэш - это просто папка, изображение - это просто файл, примеров загрузки файла из сети валом. Но так как Вы задумали делается, только когда изображения будут использоваться одни и те же и много раз. При нормальном кешировании инициация загрузки всё равно происходит по необходимости (тот же `getView` в Вашем примере). А если грузить всё сразу: во-первых юзеру придётся ждать, во-вторых он может никогда и не докрутит список до конца, а время и трафик затрачены на загрузку изображений, которые он не увидит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую все же воспользоваться библиотекой Glide (она создана тоже разработчкими Гугл, и ими же советуется для использования при работе с изображениями), поскольку она обеспечивает кеширование на разных уровнях и оптимизирована под загрузку и отобржание изображений на платформе Android.
Если же есть все же желание делать руками, то нужно вручную сделать все запросы на загрузку изображений, при этом не получив Out Of Memory, и обработав потерю связи и другие моменты. На последующих этапах нужно реализовать разные уровни кеширования: первый в памяти, посколько каждый раз читать с хранилища долго, и второй на уровне хранилища - сохранять изображение в папку в приватной или публичной директории.